# At what precision are GPT's parameters stored?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, memory-hardware

OpenAI's [technical paper on GPT-3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165) says that GPT-3 has 175 billion parameters. Several sites ([here](https://blog.inten.to/gpt-3-language-models-are-few-shot-learners-a13d1ae8b1f9), [here](https://www.hyro.ai/glossary/gpt-3/)) claim that these parameters are stored as single-precision floating-point numbers and so require 4 bytes of memory per parameter, but I don't see any citations for those claims.

At what precision are GPT-3's parameters stored? How much memory is required per parameter (on average, if variable)?